# Web scraping in php with post method, coockie and captcha

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap few data from http://iunlocker.net/check_imei.php this link.

This page have contains post method and captcha on it and it is also using a cookie. I just made inspect element and checked in network, Cookie is setting in header

Please can someone tell me, What mistake i am making there in code?

```
$ch = curl_init();
$imei="013977000272744";

curl_setopt($ch,     CURLOPT_URL,"http://iunlocker.net/check_imei.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,'_ym_uid=1460051101134309035;  _ym_isad=1; cxx=80115415b122e7c81172a0c0ca1bde40; _ym_visorc_20293771=w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array(
    'imei'=>$imei,      
     ));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $server_output;

curl_close ($ch);
```

Example IMEI 013977000272744 for manually checking.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly note that the page has a CAPTCHA but you don't include the response for it in your POST data (it would be `g-recaptcha-response`). But the whole point of CAPTCHAs is that you have to be a human to solve them, so unless you set up your script to pass the CAPTCHAs on to a human for solving this isn't going to work.

Comment: Can you suggest any other solution for by passing captcha or something like that

Comment: @user3446467 There are services you can buy that will have humans solve the CAPTCHAs for you. Other than that, there isn't really a practical way of bypassing them.

Comment: @user3446467 try using server-side js such as phantom or casper